# Mathematica how to plot objects with labels in 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, labeling

The following code plots 3 cuboids, each with a label at the lower left vertex.  The label is meant to be part of the cuboid object.  Yet, since `Text[]` is used to display the label, the label `"1"` does not hide with `cuboid #1` from the default view point.

*Mathematica* description of `Text[]` specifically calls out that

> "Text is drawn in front of all other objects."

Is there a way to display labels truly with their respective objects, so that they show or hide with their respective objects?

```
centers = Table[{Cos[2 k], Sin[2 k], 0.5 k }, {k, 3}];  
setOfCuboids =
  Table[{Graphics3D[Cuboid[centers[[k]]]],
         Graphics3D[Text[k, centers[[k]]]]},
    {k, 1, 3}];  
Show[setOfCuboids]
```

Comment: I'm suggesting this be moved to Mathematica.SE.

Comment: `Inset` is what you are looking for.